# Problem authentication django

Tags: django, apache, nginx

I have the problem of authentication django.

The first time after restarting the server everything works fine, but after some time of work (several hours) authentication will not work: when you log into the admin area gives "It seems that your browser is not configured to accept cookies. Please enable cookies, reload the page and try again. " Cookies are enabled, of course. After server restart everything worked again (some time).

Tried and Apache + mod_wsgi and nginx + FastCGI: a problem everywhere. Locally on a development server (runserver) everything works fine. What may be the problem?

Comment: Well it's definitely a problem with your server configuration and not django. So I'd add more tags to your question.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/676a90769fe2aec9?pli=1) is a discussion about how the cookie problem in admin is solved, its in mod_python though but it will give you an idea.

Comment: The PHP mhash problem occurs from the outset and not only after some period of working.